# Fstream gives error when reused on a file

Tags: c++

I have two text files.
Original Output:

```
Log.txt
Joe hello
Joe gargabash
Joe random unnecessary text
Hello
How are you?
```

Log2.txt is another text file that is initially blank.

When I run this code, it succesfully copies all of the lines that don't start with Joe. However, I want to copy the text back to the original .txt. When I uncomment out the selection I commented to try to do that, I get errors. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks so much for reading all of this mess.
For clarification, the bool STRINGCONTAINS(int, char, char, int) checks if a char array matches with another char array.

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

bool STRINGCONTAINS(bool CaseSensitive, //If this is true, we are checking a case sensitive string, if it's false, we're not.
                  char * input1, // First string [Type: Char Array]
                  char * input2, //Second String [Type: Char Array]
                  int MAXSTRINGLENGTH) // Integer representing max possible length of string.
{
    if (CaseSensitive) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<MAXSTRINGLENGTH;i++) 
        {
            if (*input1 == *input2) 
            {
                input1++; 
                input2++; 
            } else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        } 
    } else 
    {
        int char1, char2; 
        for(int i=0;i<MAXSTRINGLENGTH;i++) 
        {
            char1 = *input1; 
            char2 = *input2; 
            if (char1 == char2 || char1 == (char2+32) || char2 == (char1+32)) 
            {

                input1++; 
                input2++; 
            } else 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        } 
    }
    return 1;
}


int main() {
    int input;
                    char * loadedline = new char[192];
                    ifstream log;
                    ofstream templog;
                    log.open("log.txt");
                    templog.open("log2.txt");
                    while(log.getline(loadedline,sizeof(log)))
                    {
                        if (!STRINGCONTAINS(0,loadedline,"joe",3))
                        {
                        cout << loadedline << endl;
                        templog << loadedline << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    log.close();
                    templog.close();
                    /*ifstream templog2;
                    ofstream log2;
                    templog2.open("log2.txt");
                    log2.open("log.txt");
                    while(templog2.getline(loadedline,sizeof(templog2)))
                    {
                        log2 << loadedline << endl;
                    }
                    templog2.close();
                    log2.close;*/
                    delete[] loadedline;
                    cin >> input;
                    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: FileEdit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\jacob\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fileedit\fileedit\main.cpp(77): error C3867: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::close': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::close' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: You're missing some brackets I think `()` at the end of `log2.close;`

Comment: oh my god patchwork you are right I feel so stupid! sorry for posting this on here thank you so much!

Comment: don't feel stupid :-) a fresh pair of eyes is often all it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your program is that you are missing a parenthesis in your `log2.close.`

Change it to `log2.close();` and it will run!